# How to get element reference name in angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular5, angular7, angular8

Tried to get element reference name but not working.If anyone know please help to find the solution.

alert should be like container.Because that is element reference.

app.component.html:

```
<div (click)="test(event)" #container></div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
test(e){
   alert(e.elementRef);
   //Output should be like alert("container");
}
```

Comment: If you want to get event data you have to pass it correctly `(click)="test($event)"` not `test(event)` but in this case, we don't have `elementRef`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Kamil Augustyniak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9552890/kamil-augustyniak) wrote in his comment, use `$event` instead of `event` in your `div` element.

```
<div (click)="test($event)" #container></div>
```

The `test` method in your component class will be invoked with a [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) and you can  obtain a reference to the HTML element from its `target`, `srcElement` or `currentTarget` property (depends on browser).

```
test(event: MouseEvent): void {
   const htmlElement = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;;
   ...
}
```

> Note however that `#container` in your `div` element is an Angular template reference
>   variable that is commonly used together with a [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator.

Comment: @Nila Vaani: It works with the native HTML `div`  element as posted in your question. In your StackBlitz however you try to make it work with a custom component. Therefore, you need a different approach. Maybe you can simply pass the tab name to the `test` method. Please tell us more about your specific use case.

Comment: I want to get selected tab's element reference name.How to get it?

Comment: In your StackBlitz: Inside your `test` method, get rid of the current code and add `console.log(event.data.title)`.

Comment: Yes..title and id we can get but Is it possible or not to get template element reference name?

Comment: @Nila Vaani: I don't think this is possible. It's used by Angular at compile time and not kept in the DOM.